# Cannot archive blog post in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I am new to wordpress v5, as I see there is no archive menu for current version. How to make archieve post without delete them? Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Full docs can be found here https://wordpress.org/support/article/post-status/

To remove a post from the frontend, choose Draft from the Status dropdown. It will hide on frontend but still be saved in backend.

If you want to make it a private post so that no one but you can see it on the frontend, choose visibility and select Private.

[image: Screenshot of Visibility Option]

Comment: Hi @Unbranded Manchester, thanks for replying my question. I need to make it clear, I want archive post status, so I can display them on my custom archive page. Do you have any ideas? thanks

Comment: I'm a bit lost, your question had me thinking otherwise. If you just want a place where all "archived" posts show, just create a category called archive and then put the posts into that category.

If you want a specific post type to show in a specific template, you need to create a new template file called archive-yourcptname.php